# Wrong fraction in math mode in overleaf

Tags: math-mode, overleaf

I want to make a fraction with ln x as a numerator and ln k as a denominator, here is a text fragment from overleaf

[image: Overleaf screenshot]

But when I try to recompile I get ln3 as a coefficient, empty numerator and ln k in my denominator.

Can anyone point out typo?

[image]

Comment: Please never show an image of code. Those who want to test your code, does not want to retype everything.

Comment: Note that `\[ ... \]` does not support ``\\`` nor does it support blank lines which is why your're getting compilation errors (don't just ignore compilation errors). You might want to use `gather*` here as it does support ``\\``

Comment: 1) To break an equation in lines you need to use an environment like `split`, `align` or something ... In any case you can't use paragraphs (empty lines) to break the equation
2) After that fix you will have more reasonable results

Comment: note those red x mean you have an error, after an error you should ask about the error message (any typeset pdf output is not intended to be usable) in this case the error is the blank line after `\[` you can not have blank lines in math mode.

Answer (score 4):

Use `align*` to align the equations at the `=` sign, because `\[ .. \]` doesn't support newlines or blank lines.

```
\begin{align*}
3^{165x - 1}       &=\sqrt{k}^{x} \\
\ln 3^{165x - 1}   &=\ln k^{\frac{x}{2}} \\
(165x - 1) \ln 3   &=\frac{x}{2} \ln k \\
\frac{\ln3}{\ln k} &=...
\end{align*}
```

[image]